# how to get UTC time in yyyyMMdd’T’HHmmss’Z’ fromat in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried this below

```js
var dt = new Date();
utc = dt.toISOString();

console.log(utc)
```

which gives the result as such 2021-04-22T04:32:33.676Z

but I want this UTC DateTime in exactly yyyyMMdd’T’HHmmss’Z format...

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you don't want those extra dashes coming in the date string. You can simply remove them using `replaceAll` as below.

```js
var dt = new Date();
utc = dt.toISOString().replaceAll('-', '');
```

The output will be `20210422T04:45:28.739Z`

Comment: that wont still solve my problem..i have to remove those : and dont want milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js library which allows string format to specify. It also supports lot more operations on dates.

```js
var dt = moment();
console.log(dt.utc().format("YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss[Z]"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your explanation, I think you want the date and time to be properly displayed in utc format right?

I think using `toLocaleString()` method will give you what you want.

```
var dt = new Date();
utc = dt.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using plain javascript would be

```js
var dt = new Date();


function format(num) {
  return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}

console.log("" + dt.getUTCFullYear() + format(dt.getUTCMonth()) + format(dt.getUTCDate()) + "T" + format(dt.getUTCHours()) + format(dt.getUTCMinutes()) + format(dt.getUTCSeconds()) + "Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dt = new Date();
dt.setMilliseconds(0);
utc = dt.toISOString().replace(/[-,.,:]/g,"").replace(/000Z/, "Z");
console.log(utc)
```